# How to install ubuntu server 18.04 LTS in 64bit arm processor smartphone

Tags: server, 18.04, arm, smartphone

When i looking for local server setup, i came up with this [ubuntu server 18.04 for arm](https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm) , My old [smartphone processor](https://versus.com/en/qualcomm-snapdragon-410) is also arm 64 bit processor. can i use my old smartphone as a local server.
If its possible , I dont know , how to install ubuntu server in smartphones.
Please provide the steps.

Thanks,

Praveen R.

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server  (applies if you are on x86, x86_64, armh, s390 etc)  though ARMh cpus can differ from device to device, esp. those found on devices (which don't have the full features of those found in servers)

Comment: Phones are computers, but they are NOT tiny PCs. The differences can brick the phone. Start at https://ubports.com/ for (unofficial) phone variants of Ubuntu.